# Finish threads in the order in which they were started

Tags: java, android

I am simultaneously downloading several images in separate threads. I need to set these images to adapter. I need to finish these threads in the order in which they were started, because I am using callbacks to inform adapter and...

How can I do this(finish threads in the order in which they were started)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finishing your threads in a particular order is counter to the idea of multi-threaded programming... you don't want to start Thread 1, 2, and 3, and then dictate when they finish, because they may have tasks that take completely differing times to complete.

For example, if you are downloading two different things on two different threads, what if Thread 1 is downloading a 2 TB file and Thread 2 is downloading a 2 KB file? Obviously Thread 2 will complete long before Thread 1, and you don't want your process to have to block waiting for Thread 1 to complete... I would suggest re-thinking what you are trying to accomplish and re-design accordingly to avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

You can write one class say Mediator, pass the same instance of class to all threads. When thread finish their download they will inform Mediator by calling some method let say downloadComplete(Thread id) and mediator will keep track of ordering these thread and call back.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you probably don't necessarily care about the order in which the tasks finish, rather you want to control the order in which you handle their results.

If you submit your Runnable to an ExecutorService you will get back a Future object.  Then you can use the Future object's #get() method, http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get(), to wait for the result of each thread, in order.

If you use AsyncTask to execute each thread you can use the #get() method of AsyncTask instead, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get().

Here's a code example:

```
int time = nbrOfThreads;

List<AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>> tasks = new ArrayList<AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>>();
for (int i = 0; i < nbrOfThreads; i++) {
    final int threadNumber = i;

    AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>() {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... secondsToSleep) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(secondsToSleep[0] * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return threadNumber;
        }
    };

    tasks.add(i, task);
    task.execute(time--);
}

for (AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer> task : tasks) {
    print("Thread number: " + task.get() + " completed.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finishing the threads in order is probably not what you really want - it would be a rather artificial construct. What I think you might really want is a so-called barrier, which means letting the threads run, but then waiting until all of them are finished. After that, you may call some code (possibly from your main thread) to process results in the order you need. In order to wait for all threads to finish, just call `join()` on all of them, something like below (error-handling skipped for clarity):

```
//Create and start workers asynchronously
Thread[] workers = new Thread[NUM];
for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
    workers[i] = new MyWorkerThread(dataSlice[i]);
    workers[i].start();
}
//Barrier - wait till all threads are done
for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
    workers[i].join();
}
//Loop over generated results in some order, here reversed order just for fun
for (int i = workers.length; i > 0; i--) {
    soSomething(dataSlice[i]);
}
```